# Is there a way to copy music from one computer to another using itunes and keeping them in sync?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, music

Is there a way to copy music from one computer to another using itunes and keeping them in sync?

My understanding of how apple does their stuff is so confusing when you come from a windows/linux world.

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'in sync'. Short answer would be no - once you transfer the xml file, even if the library is in a shared location, each computer then continues from that point as a separate entity. Can you add more detail as to exactly what you're trying to do, because the method may change accordingly. Simplest is set up Home sharing, one lib, 2 'access points', but both machines need to be on to use it that way & the 'slave' machine can't really edit data

Comment: To avoid problems with sharing iTunes libraries, which became unmanageable over the years, I decided to use iCloud Match when it was made available. I can listen to (almost) all my collected music on my iDevices; on my school-owned iMac; on my personal MBAir & iMac @ home; and lastly, on my 2 Apple TVs.

Comment: I have 3 machines with iTunes libs - 1 independent & 2 I manually sync every so often. iPod/phones & pads have different partial syncs from one of the above. I guess no one solution is best for everyone - but these are 2 varied yet usable methods, @IconDaemon 's & mine.